# Polyglossia Warning: Asking to add empty feature to latin font

Tags: polyglossia

In a test file - which has a completely different purpose - I found myself in front of a notice that I don't know how to interpret. I had a look at the polyglossia documentation (where *langtag* does not exist) and on the net I found only this link (last post)
[Warnings with gloss-latex](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/284)
which seems solved here
[Use lcscript for latin check](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/commit/4151bd4b780d2fc28a391129766123cb18bd81ef)
The code is the following one:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{acerbi,
  author       = {D'Acer'bi, Fabio},
  title        = {La concezione archimedea degli oggetti matematici},
  journal      = {La Matematica nella Società e nella Cultura},
  journaltitle = {Rivista dell'Unione Matematica Italiana},
  year         = {2013},
  series       = {I},
  volume       = {VI},
  pages        = {227 - 252},
  url          = {www.academia.edu},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+supkern,RawFeature=+calt,SmallCapsFeatures={RawFeature=+apo-nosc}]{EB Garamond}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose,scauthors=all,%
giveninits,classical=true,volnumformat=strings,%
volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,commacit=true,citepages=omit,%
editionformat=superscript,indexing]%
{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}

\directlua{
   fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "apo-nosc",
    type = "chainsubstitution",
    lookups = {
      {
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
          ["quoteright.sc"] = "quoteright.fr", 
        },
      },
    },
    data = {
      rules = {
        {
          before  = { { "A", "B", "C", "D"} },
          current = { { "quoteright.sc" } },
          lookups = { 1 },
        },
      },
    },
  }
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

abc abc\footcite[239]{acerbi} abc

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

However, I receive:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: Asking to add empty feature to latin font (Languag
e="Italian" to langtag "") on input line 11.

)

Package polyglossia Warning: Asking to add empty feature to latin font (Languag
e="Italian" to langtag "") on input line 73.
```

Is there anything wrong or missing in my code? Is it a polyglossia problem? Note that I've Texlive2019, always updated. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `\PolyglossiaSetup`. This commands reinitialize the language and so you are loosing all settings done in the gloss-ldf. The correct command to add or change keys is `\SetLanguageKeys`. A visual example is for example the frenchspacing setting which you loose too with `\PolyglossiaSetup`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}

%\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false} %wrong
\SetLanguageKeys{italian}{indentfirst=false}

\begin{document}
abc. Abc

\nonfrenchspacing
abc. Abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Clear. Thank so much